# triangle with edges identified

Tags: algebraic-topology

What is the space obtained by identifying the three edges of a triangle in this way: assume the vertex of the triangle is a,b and c, then we identify ab,bc and ca.

Also, what is the fundamental group of this space。

I actually try to imagine the picture, but find I am not able to do it. So what can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fundamental group is $\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z$. The proof is very similar to the proof that the projective plane has fundamental group $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$. Write the space $X$ as the union of the interior of the triangle, denoted $A$ and a thin neighborhood of its perimeter, denoted $B$. Note that $A$ is contractible and $B$ deformation retracts to the union of the three edges, which are actually all the same edge and its two ends are identified. So $B\simeq S^1$. The intersection $A\cap B$ is homotopy equivalent to a circle as well. The map $\pi_1(A\cap B)\to \pi_1(B)$ maps a generator to three times the generator, since as you run around the perimeter of the triangle you read off the same edge three times oriented in the same direction. So, by van Kampen's theorem $\pi_1(X)=\pi_1(B)/\langle\langle \mathrm{im}\pi_1(A\cap B)\rangle\rangle\cong\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z$.